# get latest file from directory with pattern matching: Perl

Tags: perl, glob

I am newbie to perl and working on a script to find the files with pattern matching having latest modified timestamp and copy to another location.

my code is working on Mac, but having issues on windows server.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::stat;

my $UNC ="/Users/documents/";
my $FileNamePrefix = "abc*.csv";
my @files = sort {stat($a)->mtime <=> stat($b)->mtime} glob($UNC.$FileNamePrefix);

my $Recon = $files[-1];
print "Latest   = $Recon\n";
```

can someone please help me with this code, Thank you

Source location:
abc_20181.csv   (yesterdaydate)
abc_20182.csv   (todaysdate)

Target location:
abc_20182.csv

Comment: Are you handling file paths correctly?  Linux: `/foo/bar/baz`, vs Windows `c:\foo\bar\baz`

Comment: yes, no issues with the path, but sort step is not working as expected

Comment: I don't have access to a windows machine, but what happens when you print out the mtime value for a file, does it agree with what the filesystem says?  Is it a numeric value?

Comment: sorry, can you let me know syntax to print mtime,

Comment: Your code already has a `print` statement, and already invokes `stat(...)->mtime`. If you wrote those two lines you should be able to write `print stat($_)->mtime, "\n" for glob ($UNC.$FileNamePrefix);` But first I suggest just doing this: `print "$_\n" for glob($UNC.$FileNamePrefix);` to ensure you're actually getting results from `glob`.

Comment: Try to remove `use File::stat;` and sort like this: `my @files = map$$_[1], sort {$$a[0]<>$$b[0]} map[(stat($_))[9],$_], glob($UNC.$FileNamePrefix);` This uses perls built-in `stat` and does a Schwartzian transform which can be faster if you have a large number of files (stat is called fewer times like this). Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform

Comment: @KjetilS.I tried your code, I got following error syntax error at edw.pl line 587, near "<>"

Comment: @Kjetil: Please don't suggest ways to optimise code that doesn't even work. It may already be plenty fast enough.

Comment: @RakeshBobbala  Sorry, replace `<>` with `<=>`

Comment: @Borodin The main point was about changing File::stat with Perls built in stat.

Comment: @David, glob is not returning any value in windows, but working on my mac. @Kjetil$, there are only 10 files in the directory, performance is not an issue here. do I need to any support library or latest version to support this

Answer (score 2):

You could use File::Spec to create the paths, and it will create the correct syntax based on the OS it's running on. For example:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::stat;

my $UNC ="/Users/documents/";
my $FileNamePrefix = "abc*.csv";
# platform specific path:
my $pattern = File::Spec->catpath('', $UNC, $FileNamePrefix);
my @files = sort {stat($a)->mtime <=> stat($b)->mtime} glob($pattern);

my $Recon = $files[-1];
print "Latest   = $Recon\n";
```

This will make the pattern "/Users/documents/abc*.csv" on Mac and "\Users\documents\abc*.csv" on Windows.

See "perldoc File::Spec" for more examples.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your suggestions. it worked when I used `use File::DosGlob 'glob';` glob function worked as expected., can someone tell me the difference between File:DosGlob & File:Glob ?

Comment: Jeff, I am using different path on windows . windows path = "\\Users\documents\abc*.csv",  David, Thanks for your suggestion when I checked the glob function, I figured out that a library was missing.